# How to use session with angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, session, ionic-framework

I'm working with AngularJS and PHP backend, and I'm trying to display data of authenticated user, and I have **2 views**, one '**login.html**' and the other **'info.html**', **2 controllers** (one for the login function and the other for selecting the user's data) . I implement the authentication phase but for the second step I want that when the user authenticates, it will be redirected to other view (info.html) where all the information of this user will be displayed.

**I tried to** use session,but it doesn't work and I don't know why.
How can I store user's data from login function and use it in the second controller(second web service)

**login.php**

```
     <?php  
    session_start();
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");  

     if(count($data) > 0)  

     { 

    $Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
    $mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'")';

    $q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
      { 
           $token = md5($Email.time()."51395+81519851");
           $query = "UPDATE client SET token = '".$token."' WHERE EmailClient = '".$Email."'";
           mysqli_query($connect , $query);
           $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
           $_SESSION["token"] = $token; 
; 
           $result['message'] ='Logged In';
           $result['email'] =$Email;
           $result['token'] = $token;

           $resultstring=json_encode($result);
           $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
           echo $resultstring;
           exit;

      }
     $result['code'] = 603;
           $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';



    $resultstring = json_encode($result);
    $resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
    echo $resultstring;
    exit;
    }

    ?>
```

**info.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");  

 $output = array();  
 $query = "SELECT FirstName,FamilyName,EmailClient FROM client WHERE token = '".$_SESSION['token']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output[] = $row;  
      }  
      echo json_encode($output);  
 }  

 ?>
```

**loginCtrl**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'password' : $scope.password
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $state.go('info');

             }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, result)
        {      
            console.log('error');   
        });
    }

});
```

**infoCtrl :**

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state,$filter){

    $scope.loadColis = function(){ 
              $http.get("http://localhost/deb/info.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data;  
           });
      }
```

I don't know how get user authenticated data, how can I do please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: search in google for `$localstorage` or `$sessionstorage` or `$cookies`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `session` when the login function is passed without any error, like given below, you have to use `$sessionstorage` service in controller for this to work.

```
$http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config, result) {
      console.log(data);

      //Here create a session, so I am creating a "user" session with its details
      $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                firstname: data.firstname,
                lastname: data.lastname,
            }
        };

      $sessionStorage.user = $rootScope.globals;

      $state.go('info');

    }
  })
```

And then you can get details of the user on `info` page using `$sessionStorage.user.currentUser`and again you will need `$sessionStorage` service in its controller also.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I select data of current user in php file

Comment: The data will be stored here $sessionStorage.user.currentUser, I don't know how you access this to PHP